# VBA - User defined function display error

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I created a user defined function to generate a certain cell value. It is applied to a column with several thousand cells.

As part of a larger subroutine, I filter that column to check data in other cells/columns and then I clear the filter again to display the entire table.

Once I clear the filter the cells containing the function **display** `#VALUE!`. However, if I then simply click on one cell and click enter, the originally and correct cell value (generated by the function) is shown again. So this is just a display error. Can this be fixed somehow?

The function is similar to:

```
Function sampleFun(inputCell, scopeCell As Range)

    If scopeCell.Text = "AAA" Then
        If Application.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A:A"), inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
            sampleFun = "OK"
        Else
            sampleFun = "CHECK"
        End If
    Else
        If Application.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A:A"), inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
            sampleFun = "OK"
        Else
            sampleFun = "CHECK"
        End If
    End If
    
End Function
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: "The function is similar to" - but not exactly?  Those two If blocks seem the same.

Comment: When all else fails, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text). The Text property is most often used for a range of one cell. If the range includes more than one cell, the Text property returns Null, except when all the cells in the range have identical contents and formats.